# Use operator[] inside class that inherits std::vector

Tags: c++, inheritance, stdvector, this-pointer

#### Doesn't work

```
class A : public std::vector<int>
{
    explicit A()
    {
        push_back(5);
        std::cout << *this[0]; 
    }
}
```

---

```
error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'A')
std::cout << *this[0];'
```

---

Replacing `*this[0]` with `at(0)` makes it work, though. I find it very wierd that `*this[0]` returns an object of type `A` and not `int`, as `at(0)` does. Shouldn't they work the same way in this example?

Comment: The standard classes aren't meant for deriving in most cases. Just use these as a member.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Really? But that is unnecessary hassle. I have to make a getter and setter and so on. And this works fine for me

Comment: My example: `class Grid`, `std::vector grid`. Those sound too similar, so why not merge them? I also tried getter and setter via `operator()` but that was hard to distinguish from the class itself as well.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry. I have learned by now. Always learning...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message gives it away:

```
error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'A')
```

Where does that `A` come from? `this` is an `A* const`, and the way to get objects from pointers is dereferencing - so that'd be `this[0]`.

You want:

```
std::cout << (*this)[0];
```

The [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) of `operator[]` is higher than dereference - you need to ensure that `*this` happens first. Of course, alternatively, you could write this mess:

```
std::cout << this->operator[](0);
```

but I'd recommend the parentheses.

Comment: Huh. Thanks for that amazingly fast answer! But why is that? What do the parenteses change?